# Cause a UAC popup from commandline without custom tools

Tags: windows-7, uac, runas

In Win7, a user can right-click on a program and choose 'Run as administrator'. You get a popup, but do **not** have to enter the administrator password.

I would like to get the same functionality, but from the commandline - in particular, from inside a `.bat` file.

I am [aware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813005/how-to-use-runas-without-being-prompt-for-password) of the built-in `runas` command, but I have not found a way to use that that doesn't end up asking for a password at some point.

I am also [aware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282448/windows-7-and-vista-uac-programatically-requesting-elevation-in-c-sharp) of the `Process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";` method, which does exactly what I want, but requires me creating a custom .NET app.

Is there any way, using only built-in commandline tools in Win7, to accomplish this?

---

**Update:** Thanks to uSlackr, I worked out this command:

```
powershell Start-Process cmd.exe -Verb RunAs
```

Of course, the `cmd.exe` is just a placeholder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Start-Process cmdlet in Powershell with the RunAs verb.  More here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347667.aspx

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I updated the question with a working example.

Comment: Any equivalent on Windows XP?

Comment: Powershell is available for XP.

Comment: XP doesn't have UAC so the question is not relevant to it

Comment: @nponeccop I assume the motivation for wanting to run under Windows XP is to let a single script run on both Windows 7 and Windows XP, not have one path for Windows 7 that has PowerShell and UAC and a second path for Windows XP that has no PowerShell and no UAC.

Answer (score 1):

**Simply run the cmd.exe as administrator.**

The keyboard shortcut for this is [shift] + [enter] after you have selected the commandline from the start menu. A UAC window should pop up.

OR

**Run everything as Admin**

Not recommended for everyday usage, but there is also a built in administrator account that you can activate in windows that will simply run any and all applications as root. In an administrative cmd:

```
net user administrator /active:yes
```

Change that to '/active:no' if you want to disable the account. A brief intro [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/enable-the-hidden-administrator-account-on-windows-vista/).

Comment: Regarding your first suggestion: Sorry, I was not clear. I want to do this from inside a .bat file (question updated).

Comment: Regarding your second suggestion: I ran this, and got "System error 5 has occurred. Access is denied."

Comment: Even running cmd.exe as admin?

Comment: The whole point of this question is that I am running this command as a non-admin user and I want to temporarily elevate permissions.