# Open graphical runas window from script on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, batch, uac, run-dialog

My customers don't want to do a SHIFT+Right Click > "Run as" on a script.

So I am looking for a way to do exactly the same from a batch script.

**How to open this window on Windows XP from a batch script?**

[image: Run as windows XP]

The user needs to launch the program as another local user.

**EDIT**

I found a solution for Windows 7 [here](https://superuser.com/a/420317/217485) but it doesnt' work on XP...

Comment: [ShellRunas](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc300361) could be a solution but I am astonished this feature doesn't exist on XP...

Answer (score 0):

CredTask.vbs:

```
On Error Resume Next

strComputer = "." 'local computer
strUserName = "Domain\User" 'user name
strPassword = "Password" 'user password

strCommandLine="calc.exe"

Set objSWbemLocator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
Set objServices = objSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(strComputer, "root\CIMV2", strUserName, strPassword, Null, Null, 0)

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    WScript.Echo Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    WScript.Quit
End If

Set objClass = objServices.Get("Win32_Process")
Res = objClass.Create(strCommandLine, Null, Null, PID)
If Res <> 0 Then
    WScript.Echo "Error ru application code: " & Res
End If
```

[Encode a Script](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/16439c02-3296-4ec8-9134-6eb6fb599880)

[GreyMagic Online Script Decoder](http://www.greymagic.com/security/tools/decoder/)