# Avoid launching explorer to UAC-elevate a program from shell

Tags: windows-7, shell-script, uac

I'm a member of administrators group on Windows 7. I need to run `foo.exe` from a Cmd or Powershell. The exe file requires elevation to work but the elevation is not specified in its manifest.

Usually I have to do `start .` to open Explorer, right-click the exe and select Run as administrator.

Is there an easier way? I'm not going to turn UAC off, I don't want to have the password remembered passwords or to avoid the prompt. I just want to avoid the need to launch the Explorer window.

I'm a member of administrators group. I don't want to run as another user, I only want to see the passwordless UAC prompt I see when I do myself when right clicking in Explorer, but without opening the explorer, running third-party tools, disabling UAC, ability to do the same from scripts or remembering credentials.

I just want to invoke the usual UAC prompt without an intermediate step.

To clarify, I want the following sequence:

1. Windows 7, UAC on, I'm in administrators group, UAC prompt is set to answer yes/no.
2. Open a non-elevated command prompt and navigate to a deep folder and do other tasks.
3. I run 'elevate-command-sequence foo.exe' and an UAC prompt opens exactly the same way it opens when I right-click in Explorer. Current directory for foo.exe is set to the deep folder I'm in.

I wonder if such `elevate-command-sequence` exists in cmd or powershell out of the box.

Comment: You can use the `runas` and provide an `Administrator` account and the password to do this.  An example would of the command is `runas /user:"Administrator"`

Comment: That was answered zillion times and it's not what I want. I'm a member of administrators group. I don't want to run as another user, I only want to see the passwordless UAC prompt I see when I do myself when right clicking in Explorer, but without opening the explorer, running third-party tools, disabling UAC, ability to do the same from scripts or remembering credentials. I just want to invoke the usual UAC prompt without an intermediate step.

Comment: If its not what you want clarify your question.  I suggest you modify the manifest file.  I highly suspect if you `runas` the same profile your using you won't get a password propmpt.  Since you were sort of rude to me I don't plan on returning to this question.

Comment: I only wanted to mention the long list of other scenarios I have read about to ensure the audience that I did search for existing answers. I'm sorry for sounding rude, insulting was not my intent.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cause a UAC popup from commandline without custom tools](http://superuser.com/questions/420315/cause-a-uac-popup-from-commandline-without-custom-tools)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is reasonably answered here: https://superuser.com/a/420317/98646

> ```
> powershell Start-Process cmd.exe -Verb RunAs
> ```
>
> Of course, the cmd.exe is just a placeholder.

Answer (score 2):

The command prompt can not natively launch elevated applications if itself was not launched in a elevated state. It sucks, but it is just part of windows behavior.

If you want to work around it you must use a 3rd party tool that will launch the program elevated for you. From some quick googling I found [ELE](http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.24), this will let you run a program in a elevated state from a non elevated command prompt (after a UAC pop up of course)

```
c:\>ele foo.exe
```

I am sure there are a million more programs that do this, heck I could write one in C# here in this answer.

```
namespace Sandbox_Console
{
    public class Program
    {

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process newProcess = new Process();
            newProcess.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
            newProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            newProcess.StartInfo.FileName = args[0];
            newProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Join(" ", args, 1, args.Length - 1);
            newProcess.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Now that code is very fragile and it can not handle stuff like spaces in arguments right now but it would not be difficult to add.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this Group policy Setting Change May help you :

1. Start-->`run`-->`gpedit.msc`
2. Navigate to  `Computer Configuration --> Policies-->Windows Settings-->Security Settings -->Local Policies-->Security Options`

[image]

3.Change the `behavior of elevation prompt for administrator` (you can derive as you wish)

Restart the computer to make changes effect

Comment: I'd qualify this as 'disabling UAC'. It's not what I want. I want the prompt to remain in place.

Comment: @nponeccop - You can't have everything in life.  UAC is designed in a specific, elevation of the process, any user except the one that is currently logged will require a password if the account itself has a password.

Comment: It's exactly what I want. I'm the user who logged in, and I'm in admin group. If it asks me for my pass in UAC prompt or prompts yes/no it's not a problem.